# Application abort on Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)

Tags: java, linux, javafx

I am trying to open file browser in a JavaFX application. I am using `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)` . It works fine in Windows machine but in linux it give message

> Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked
>   Aborted

and close entire application. Any suggestion how to open file explorer in linux using java?

Comment: does your OS support opening files in a file manager? which linux kernel and gui are you using?

Comment: I am not very sure but yes my OS supports. I am using 3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64 version kernel and javafx application for GUI